# Calling a BOOL method and dealing with the result

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, boolean, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to work out the correct way to approach some methodology.

**Workflow**
When a game is created, I would like to first search to see if a game already exists with this user. If there is a game I will not create one and show a message to the user.

At present I have two methods:

```
+(void)createNewGameAgainst:(PFUser *)user2 withCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL success))completionHandler

+(BOOL)checkIfGameAlreadyExistsAgainst:(PFUser *)opponentUser
```

The createNewGame... method is called first. Then within this I make a call to [self checkIfGameAlreadyExistsAgainst:user2];.

How do I check the result of the second method, from within the first? So how do I determine what the BOOL value is of the call to the method checkIfGameAlreadyExistsAgainst?

Is this the correct way to approach this or is there a better/cleaner way possibly?

Comment: How have you tried calling `checkIfGameAlreadyExistsAgainst` and using the return value?

Comment: from the rest of your questions, I assume you can't possible be looking for `if([self checkIfGameAlreadyExistsAgainst:user2] == YES) { }`

Comment: @Turch - Yes as simple as that, please submit as an answer. Would you say this is the correct approach for what I am trying to achieve, or anything different?

Comment: @StuartM Yeah, I'd say that's the correct approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of a function can be used like a variable:

```
BOOL gameExists = [self checkIfGameAlreadyExistsAgainst:user2];   // assign result to a new variable

if(gameExists == YES)   // compare result to YES
{
}
```

You can skip creating a new variable and just compare the result

```
if ([self checkIfGameAlreadyExistsAgainst:user2] == YES)    // compare result directly
{
}
```

And when the type is BOOL, you can omit the comparison and just do this:

```
if ([self checkIfGameAlreadyExistsAgainst:user2])
{
}
```